# Prevent numbers on the x axis from merging together in SSRS stacked bar chart?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, graph

One question to pretty this graph up:

- How to prevent numbers on the x axis from merging together in SSRS stacked bar chart?

[image: SSRS Graph]

Answer (score 0):

Try to play around with the SmartLabels under the properties pane of each series.

Comment: I used the IIF program flow to adjust the legend, still not clear on how to adjust those nasty little values on the x axis